# .htaccess working on remote server but does not work on localhost.  Getting 404 errors on localhost

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, localhost

**MY PROBLEM:**

When I visit localhost the site does not work.  It shows some text from the site but it seems the server can not locate any other files.  Here is a snippet of the errors from firebug:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - localhost/css/popup.css"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - localhost/css/style.css"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - localhost/css/player.css"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - localhost/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - localhost/js/jquery.js"
```

It seems my server is looking for the files in the wrong places.  For example, localhost/css/popup.css is actually located at localhost/app/webroot/css/popup.css.

I have my site setup on a remote server with the same exact configurations and it works perfectly fine.  I am just having this issue trying to run the site on my laptop at localhost.  I edited my VirtualHosts file DocumentRoot and  to  /home/user/public_html/site.com/public/app/webroot/ and this reduces some errors but I feel that this is wrong and sort of hacking it since I didn't use these setting on my production server which works.

The last note I want to make is that the website uses dynamic URLs.  I dont know if that has anything to do with it. For example, on the production server the URLS are: site.com/#hello/12321.

**HERES WHAT I AM WORKING WITH:**

I have a LAMP server setup on my laptop which runs on Ubuntu 11.10.

I have enabled mod_rewrite:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Then I edited my Virtual Hosts file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName  localhost
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html/site.com/public

    <Directory /home/user/public_html/site.com/public/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I restarted apache.
My website is using cakePHP.  This is the directory structure of the website:
"/home/user/public_html/site.com/public" contains:

```
index.php app cake plugins vendors
```

These are my .htaccess files:

/home/user/public_html/site.com/public/app/.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

/home/user/public_html/site.com/public/app/webroot/.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have .htaccess in your app/ and app/webroot dirs, but nothing in your root directory.

You should have the file: /home/user/public_html/site.com/public/.htaccess

```
RewriteRule    ^$    app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1    [L]
```

OR

Change your docroot to

```
DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html/site.com/public/app/
```

Both of these answers are assuming public/index.php isn't running some sort of advanced routing on the URI. Having nested .htaccess files doing rewrites is messy though.

Answer (score 1):

Your site is under `/home/user/public_html/site.com/public`.

It contains: `index.php app cake plugins vendors`

And your root `.htaccess` file is:

```
RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
```

So this means: whatever it is, go to the `webroot` folder in your installation.

But I don't see any  `webroot` folder. Am I missing something?

Comment: My webroot folder is located: /home/user/public_html/site.com/public/app/webroot/.  It contains "css  css.php  favicon.ico  files  img  index.php  js  template". Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I see no mention of logs. **Firebug is not Apache error logs**. There is no substitute for the Apache error logs in this case, so **crank up error logging and check error.log**

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#errorlog

Answer (score 0):

On your laptop, do you have AllowOverride set in your apache config somehwere to allow the use of .htaccess files?

See:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride

For details.

Or just add the following to your `httpd.conf` and restart apache:

```
AllowOverride All
```

If that helps, then check out the above link and refine the `AllowOverride` directive.
If it does not help, then take out the `AllowOverride` you added (but leave in any onthers that were already there) and restart apache.